# Multiplying elements of array from chucks

Tags: python

I am trying to create a python script where I have using regular expressions matched 2 cols from a file (as two arrays).

```
import re
import numpy as np
filename = ('test')
a = []
b = []

with open (filename,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            v1 = re.findall(r"^\s+\d+.\d+\s+(\d+.\d+)",line)
            v2 = re.findall(r"^\s+\d+.\d+\s+\d+.\d+\s+\d+.\d+\s+(\d+.\d+)",line)
            a.append(v1)
            b.append(v2)
```

Following this, using an generator - yeild, I have made chunks of 10 rows each from the two arrays

```
n = 10
def chunks(a):
    for i in range(0, len(a), n):
            yield a[i:i + n]
as = []
a = chunks(a)
for x in range(0,20):
globals()['as%s' % x] = np.array(next(a))
def chunks(b):
    for j in range(0, len(b), n):
            yield b[j:j + n]
bs = []
b = chunks(b)
for x in range(0,20):
         globals()['bs%s' % x] = np.array(next(b))
```

So now I have 20 arrays of a and 20 of b each containing 10 rows/elements.
Using this I want to compute a product of the as1[0] * bs1[0]

```
for k in range(0,20):
    for l in range (0,10):
            prod = (globals()['cvs%s' % k][l] * globals()['hills%s' % k][l])
            print (prod)
```

but this isn't working, it would be great if someone helps me around calculating the product. I am new to python.

THank you,
have a great day.

Comment: Array and list are different things in Python...

Comment: Why are you using globals like that?

Comment: Since i tried using `a[k][l]` which didn't work
For eg. in `a` there are 20 arrays with name `a1,a2,a3,...,a20` but each such array has 10 elements. So to access the array element I have used Globals (might be dumb to use it but found it online.

Comment: Why not just use a list properly? Usually "I found it online" is a reason *not* to use arbitrary code snippets :)